# Using HashMap for Node & Graph Data Structures

Tags: java, graph, hashmap, vertex

I never saw any textbook using HashMap for Node or Graph classes.

Here is my implementation of the Node and Graph classes. Do they have O(1) time complexity for all major operations like checking a node, checking a neighbor, get the distance between two nodes, etc?

```
//T as the type of the content in each node
//D as the type of the distance between the nodes
class Node<T,D>{
    private T content;
    private HashMap<T,D> neighbors;
    private boolean marked;

    //an example method
    protected boolean hasNeighbor(T t){
        return this.neighbors.containsKey(t);
    }

    //another example method
    protected D distanceTo(T t){
        return this.neighbors.get(t);
    }

    //this class also overrides equals() and hashCode() methods so that every two nodes
    //equal to each other if and only if their content equal to each other
}
```

also, here's my idea about the Graph class

```
public class Graph<T,D>{
    private HashMap<T, Node<T,D>> nodes;

    //an example method
    public D distanceBetween(T a, T b){
        return this.nodes.get(a).distanceTo(b);
    }
}
```

So, everything can be done in constant time, right? If so, why can't we see any textbook using this kind of implementation?

Comment: `distanceBetween` is not `O(1)` in your implementation. If you use adjacency matrix, `isNeighbor` can be done in `O(1)`. AFAIK distance between two nodes can't be done in constant time for general graphs.

Comment: @Bill why `distanceBetween()` is not `O(1)`? Both `get(...)` in the hash maps are constant time, right?

Answer (score 0):

The worst-case lookup time for a hashmap is `O(n)`, if you do not provide a good hashcode, however, you can consider that hashmaps have asymptotic constant lookup time.

I think your implementation of graph is fine (I'm not sure if it is semantically correct, but in principle I don't see why it cannot be implemented using Hashmaps when you have key/value bindings). To answer your main question I think, in a course book on computer science abstraction is more important than an actual implementation.
The `HashMap` implementation in Java has specific assumptions about hashcode/equality contracts and I think most textbooks try to avoid such details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still got a question. Consider the `HashMap<T, Vertex<T,D>>` in the `Graph` class. First, since it's a hashmap, it takes almost constant time to get the `Vertex` object for a given `T` object. Second, since the same `T` object is an attribute of the `Vertex` object, it also takes constant time to get the `T` object for a given `Vertex` object. Is it good to generalize this idea so that we can implement something that works like a bi-map?

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the distance from one node to its immediate neighbours is rarely an issue in algorithms on graphs. Consider, for instance, Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path between A and some other node (not necessarily a neighbour) Z. The algorithm proceeds from the current node (initially A) to all neighbours that haven't been visited yet. Any container that can be (quickly) iterated will do; a (Hash)Map isn't even first choice for that.

Also, HashMaps tend to consume rather more space than is required for the data istself. Multiplied by a large number of nodes, that can be an issue (or at least could have been).

Lastly, if the number of neighbours is, on average, rather small (~10), even a dumb sequential search of a List will give you a neighbour based on its content. Moreover, since graphs are frequently stable, even larger numbers could be handled efficiently by sorting and binary search.

And textbook assume that readers know about data structures and can choose an implmentation according to their specific needs. As Ali has pointed out: the abstraction is more important than implementation hacks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But I still got two more question. First, is it true that people usually don't like the idea of getting better-looking time complexity by taking up more storage space? Second, is there an implementation of graphs that works well on almost all different cases (i.e. is there a library like java.ArrayList)? (BTW I just learnt about data structures like graphs and the algorithms on them in the last semester. So please forgive me if my questions look dumb)

Comment: First: No, not with people who have learned that there's a tradeoff between execution time and memory requirements. Second: JGraphT is one and google will find you others. You'll have to judge for yourself.